# kubectl port-forward is not working/too slow

Tags: kubernetes, centos, kubernetes-helm, traefik

I am setting up Traefik in my CentOS VM. I tried to port-forward as specified here:

https://github.com/jakubhajek/traefik-workshop/tree/3cbbb3b8d3dbafcb2a56f3bb715fee41ba8ffe8b/exercise-2

It displays the following, taking hours, and does nothing:

```
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:9000 -> 9000
Forwarding from [::1]:9000 -> 9000
Handling connection for 9000
Handling connection for 9000
Handling connection for 9000
Handling connection for 9000
```

Please advise what I should do to make the `kubectl port-forward` work.

Comment: What happens when you hit "http://localhost:9000/dashboard" ?

Comment: It says `404 page not found`

Answer (score 2):

kubectl port-forward makes a specific Kubernetes API request. That means the system running it needs access to the API server, and any traffic will get tunneled over a single HTTP connection.

If it is saying 404 page not found, then probably there is something wrong with the deployment ( application ) as the port 9000 is listening and opened connection. So you can check whether you have done port-forwarding to the right pod or not.